# Search symbols again after setting debug-file-directory

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb

I've established a build process that makes binaries and then separates the debug info from them (build-ids are enabled).

The build can also generate the `.gdbinit` files with the lines like `set debug-file-directory <dir>`, so the debugger can find them (there are lots of executables and libraries in the project).

But when I run `$ gdb myprogram`, gdb can't find the symbols. I have to do `(gdb) file myprogram` to redo the search for the debug-symbols file. It seems that `.gdbinit` is executed after opening `myprogram`.

How to make it automatic?

Comment: `.gdbinit` is executed. It sets the `debug-file-directory`, but it does it too late. The `.gdbinit` files are in the build dirs, because they're generated there.

Comment: are you sure? Can you check with "(gdb) show debug-file-directory" ? Can you provide the output of this command?

Comment: @pmod, yes, it shows a correct directory (that it got from the .gdbinit). I just have to do `file myprogram` to actually start using that. But if the `set debug-file-directory <dir>` is in the `~/.gdbinit` of the home dir, it's applied immediately, so the `$ gdb myprogram` is enough.

Comment: can you check then "(gdb) show auto-load local-gdbinit" ?

Comment: It complains loudly when the `add-auto-load-safe-path` is disabled and a local `.gdbinit` is found. So, "Auto-loading of .gdbinit script from current directory is on".

Answer (score 2):

Basically, *.gdbinit* file is used to setup *debugging environment* (add aliases for long commands, load custom commands, setup print modes, etc. ), not a particular *debugging session*.

Taking a look at [gdb startup order](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Startup.html#Startup) and considering that home *.gdbinit* works ok, it cannot be achieved with local *.gdbinit* file (order of operations should be **set debug-file-directory**, **file**). I think you can modify your build/debug process for using gdb wrapper script with gdb command script (the same as  .gdbinit but call it start.gdb for example to avoid confusion):

```
gdb_x:
#!/bin/sh
gdb -x ./start.gdb "$@"

start.gdb:
# this file is generated for .. by ...
set debug-file-directory <>
set debug-file-directory <>
```

Or, as a workaround, if you can bare with the fact that commands will run twice:

```
gdb -x ./.gdbinit <>
```

which can be avoided with (and deserves again wrapper script):

```
gdb -iex "set auto-load local-gdbinit off" -x ./.gdbinit <>
```

Comment: I give up. I'll group all debug files of the project in one dir and edit the global `.gdbinit`. It's a per-project config, but at least it's not too confusing for the people.